# android - how can I add a subscription to a public calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, subscribe

I would like to make it possible for users to easily subscribe to public calendars in my app.

I have been searching the api but have not found anything regarding adding subscriptions to existing public calendars. Does code even exist to do this? If anyone could point me in te right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I do not want to add a single event, but rather a subscription to a preexisting calendar.

Comment: I've been searching for something similar.  I haven't been able to figure out how to subscribe to someone else's public Google calendar on my android.  Nor have I been able to allow users to subscribe to my public Google calendar on one of my sites.  I will be watching this post to see if you get any bites.  Good question.